# VBA: Get value from dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I tried using dictionaries in VBA. Microsoft Scripting Runtime is activated and I managed to fill it with the data I want (the `For Each` loop shows me as much). But then I didn't get any further

```
Sub Report2()

    Dim wbAggr As Workbook, wbMonat As Workbook
    Dim wsAggr As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long, lRowAggr As Long
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim key As Variant


    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set wbAggr = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsAggr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    lRowAggr = wsAggr.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For iRow = 2 To lRowAggr
        dict.Add wsAggr.Cells(iRow, "K"), iRow
    Next iRow


    For Each key In dict.Keys  '-> returns 2500 key+item pairs
        Debug.Print key, dict(key)
    Next key

    Debug.Print "dict.Keys(20): " & dict.Keys(20)
    Debug.Print "dict.Items(20): " & dict.Items(20)
    Debug.Print "dict.Exists('101010074'): " & dict.Exists("101010074")
    Debug.Print "dict.Exists(101010074): " & dict.Exists(101010074)
    Debug.Print "dict('101010074'): " & dict("101010074")
    Debug.Print "dict(101010074): " & dict(101010074)
    Debug.Print "VarType(dict.Keys(20)): " & VarType(dict.Keys(20))
End Sub
```

Output for the `Debug.Print` statements:

- dict.Keys(20): 101010074
- dict.Items(20): 22
- dict.Exists('101010074'): False
- dict.Exists(101010074): False
- dict('101010074'):
- dict(101010074):
- edit: VarType(dict.Keys(20)): 8 (= string)

So if I'm reading this right (probably not), there is a key "101010074", but then why does `dict.Exists("101010074")` return `False`?

Output of `For Each` loop with `Debug.Print key, dict(key)`:

[image: Output of <code>Debug.Print key, dict(key)</code>]

Comment: Maybe because you added a value and you are asking for a String. Dictionaries are pretty annoying with formats, LCase and UCase... to check the value for a key the correct sintax is: `Debug.Print dict(Key)`

Comment: @Damin you can make dictionaries case insensitive using `dict.CompareMode = TextCompare`

Comment: In the Excel file the column is formatted as text. And even if the keys aren't strings, shouldn't `dict.Exists(101010074)` return `True` in this case? 

Anyway, `Debug.Print VarType(dict.Keys(20))` returns `8`, which is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're adding your key the dictionary is setting the key to the `Range` object and not the `Value`. Use the following instead

```
For iRow = 2 To lRowAggr
    dict.Add wsAggr.Cells(iRow, "K").Value2, iRow
Next iRow
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it still goes through and displays all entries. Besides, if `dict.Add` adds the key first and then the item, then `dict.Add wsAggr.Cells(iRow, "K"), iRow` should result in `101010074` being the key because that's what's stored in column K

Comment: @NoNameNo123 Looking at it further realised the issue - have edited my answer

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple (either that or I was losing my mind). Thanks for saving my sanity!

Comment: @NoNameNo123 Just one additional observation. You will run into issues if you have duplicate values in column `K`. It may be worthwhile using the row number as your key as this will be unique.

Comment: Good call and thanks for the tip, but the whole point is that column K is full of unique values (against which I will compare another column full of values). Have a great day!

Comment: @NoNameNo123 Fair enough - as long as it is covered